# couldn't send retry message on botframework sdk v3

Tags: botframework

I've been building a solution on Bot Framework V3 using Direct Line.
The bot is working fine but when user makes a question for the FIRST TIME it throws a 'couldn't send retry' message on the chat window and then replies to the user.
My application uses LUIS and QnA Maker.
The problem always happens when a QnA Maker answer has been requested.
My best guess is that QnaMakers triggers timeouts until answers have been cached in memory..
Root Dialog code snippet:

```
   [LuisIntent("QnAMaker")]
    public async Task QnAMaker(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
            await context.Forward(new QnaMakerDialog(), AfterQnADialog, context.Activity, CancellationToken.None);                

    }
```

QnaMaker code snippet:

```
 [Serializable]
    public class QnaMakerDialog : QnAMakerDialog
    {
        public QnaMakerDialog() : base(new QnAMakerService(new QnAMakerAttribute(BellaMain.GlobalVariable.QnAAuthKey, BellaMain.GlobalVariable.QnAKnowledgebaseId, "Couldn't find your answer. Can you re-phrase it please?", 0.5, 1, BellaMain.GlobalVariable.QnAEndpointHostName)))
        {
        }

        protected override async Task RespondFromQnAMakerResultAsync(IDialogContext context, IMessageActivity message, QnAMakerResults result)
        {
            var messageString = result.Answers.First().Answer;         
            await context.PostAsync(messageString);
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
}
```

Message controller code:

```
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// POST: api/Messages
    /// Receive a message from a user and reply to it
    /// </summary>


    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        //Global Variables Load
        BellaMain BellaMain = new BellaMain();
        try
        {
            BellaMain.AppStartup();
        }
        catch
        {
            activity.Text = "DB access error";
        }
        BellaMain.GlobalVariable.SetGlobalCustomerID(BellaMain.GlobalVariable.CustomerID);
        // LUIS Credentials Set            
        var luisAttributes = new LuisModelAttribute(BellaMain.GlobalVariable.LuisModelID, BellaMain.GlobalVariable.LuisSubscriptionKey, LuisApiVersion.V2, BellaMain.GlobalVariable.LuisDomainName);
        var luisService = new LuisService(luisAttributes);
        var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
        var activityFromID = "";

        switch (activity.Type)
        {
            case ActivityTypes.Message:
                //** Display a "is typing kind" animation before the bot reply
                var isTypingReply = activity.CreateReply(String.Empty);
                isTypingReply.Type = ActivityTypes.Typing;
                ConnectorClient isTypingConnector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
                await isTypingConnector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(isTypingReply);
                await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog(luisService).DefaultIfException());                                                  
                break;
            case ActivityTypes.Event:
                var eventActivity = activity.AsEventActivity();
                if (eventActivity.Name == "requestWelcomeDialog")
                {
                    var reply = activity.CreateReply();
                    if (BellaMain.GlobalVariable.BellaWelcomeGreetings != "")
                    {
                        reply.Text = BellaMain.GlobalVariable.BellaWelcomeGreetings;
                        await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
                        BellaMain.BotWait("while");
                    }
                    // Launches the User Data Collection Form If the Case
                    if (BellaMain.GlobalVariable.FlagCollectUserDataOnConversationStart)
                    {
                        await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.CustomUserDataCollectFormDialogDispacher().DefaultIfException());
                    }
                    //Launches Bella Help If the Case
                    if (BellaMain.GlobalVariable.FlagBellaHelpOnConversationStart)
                    {
                        await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.CustomBellaHelpDispacher().DefaultIfException());
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }       
}
```

How can I avoid this message to happen? Thx in advance

Comment: The code you've shown here should not cause timeouts, or errors in response to an initial question.  Which exact version of the v3 BotBuilder sdk are you using?

Comment: Indeed. I'm using: Microsoft.Bot.Builder v3.19.1.44133  and Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure v3.16.3.40383. Could it be a client or browser issue?

Comment: How is the MessagesController setup?

Comment: Just added the code in the question body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a call to

```
MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(activity.ServiceUrl);
```

before using the `ConnectorClient`.  This will ensure the url for the outgoing message is considered trusted.

Comment: Spot on! The problem disappeared. You are the man. Thanks a lot Eric!

Comment: By the way, I've also changed the make root call to: await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog(luisService).DefaultIfException()));

Comment: There might be some scaling/performance issues with that implementation, but most bots do not receive enough traffic for it to be a problem.(just something to keep in mind,if your bot will be getting a lot of traffic)